# How to check if a value is listed in a database using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I check to see if a web page is listed in a database and if its not add it to the database.

How can I do this using PHP and MySQL.

Sorry if I'm vague I'm new to PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Well, do you already have a database set up? What is its structure?

Comment: You definitely need to elaborate further. As a guide, what do you want to achieve? What have you done so far to achieve that (or your current set-up)?

Comment: look for a tutorial, do not ask on S.O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example.

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('host','user','pass');

$sql ="SELECT url FROM yourTable WHERE url = 'http://example.com/foo'";

$qid = mysql_query($sql, $db);

if (mysql_num_rows($qid) == 0) {
    $sql ="INSERT INTO yourTable (url) VALUES ('http://example.com/foo')";
    mysql_query($sql, $db);
}
```

However you should add error checking after the mysql_connect() and the mysql_query() functions.

See: http://php.net/mysql_query and http://php.net/mysql_connect